# Android Navigation component with viewpager2 weird behavior

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a FragmentMain which consists of a viewpager2.

It looks like this.

```
private var mAdapterPager : MyFragmentStateAdapter? = null    

override fun onViewCreated(bundle:SaveStateInstance?){
   //....
   mAdapterPager = MyFragmentStateAdapter(childFragmentManager, requireActivity().lifeCycle)
   binding.viewPager2.adapter = mAdapterPager
}
```

The FragmentStateAdapter of the viewpager2 has five fragments.

It works as I intented on most cases, but whenever I navigate to another fragment, and come back by navigateUp(), the following happens.

1. As the fragment is recreated, the onViewCreated() of the FragmentMain runs. The adapter is reinitiated and attached to the viewpager2.
2. But in my emulator, the exact screen which I left is persisting, including the viewpager2's currentItem property.
3. By doing some logging, the fragments inside the MyFragmentStateAdapter seems to be recreated, but is never attached to the screen.
4. As for, whenever I try to access the fragment's inside the FragmentStateAdapter by the adapter instance directly, it will fail.
5. Excluding such case, the app works perfectly fine. Accessing some functions of fragments inside the FragmentStateAdapter via shared viewModels also works.
6. As a conclusion, the app works except that it lost access to the fragments that are actually attached to the viewpager2.

What is this behavior? I've tried searching for the behavior of viewpager2, but I could not find a sufficient answer for this.

I know that accessing fragment objects directly is not a good practice, but I'm very curious where those references of the fragments inside the viewpager2 are.